# Setting a variable in objective c to be visible in another view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a viewController `FilterViewController.m` and `.h`

I have a stepper which sets a variable named `value` with data type of int, with the variable value between 1 and 16.

The stepper sets the value in the method `stepperValueChanged` and in this method I need to set a 'global' variable to be accessed in my `FirstViewController`.

How can I set the variable scope to be visible in FirstViewController?

I understand that I can use a class to do this, but am unsure how. This is mainly for learning points.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use global variables in your code, and if you have to use them it means a bad implementation.

You need to check how both classes are connected, maybe you can use a delegate to inform that the value has changed, or send a notification with the new value, for example.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting. May I ask why using a global variable is bad? In C i would occasionally use them and it didn't seem like bad practice? I suppose I only used them in procedural programs as opposed to OOP ones

Comment: Is it hard to use them properly, you have to be aware of which classes are accessing to them and when, and you can make easy mistakes, so it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass along that value and then use a delegate method (or unwind segue if using storyboards) to send updated values back.

Another viable choice (though overkill here I think) is to use a singleton to create an object that gets updated.

As an alternative (though not recommended unless these two controllers have no connection except for that value passing), you could use `CoreData` or `NSUserDefaults` to persist the value.